# Failover handling with Community Edition of Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am using Community Edition of Neo4j on my local machine. Is there any way for handling failover (Failover mechanism is present in Enterprise Edition)?. 
One option 1 have thought of is to take the backup of directory on real time and run the new Neo4j installation on backup directory. Is there any way to manage it through any script or some software like Load Balancer which will enable the backup on same port and IP on failover of main Server.

If anyone has prepared setup of handling failover with Community Edition. Please share.

Comment: which language do you use?

Comment: I am trying to prepare a failover setup through a Shell Script.

Comment: You can use something like NeoClient which has failover built in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copying over the store directory while the database is running is a dangerous operation that might result in corrupted data.

Of course you can write a clustering solution on top of Neo4j community yourself, but be assured that you need to invest multiple man-years to do this in production ready way. That's why Neo4j enterprise already solved that problem for you.

The recommended way of course is to use enterprise edition. Contact Neo4j sales folks to gather more information regarding licensing and prices.

Comment: As per my use case, my application will only read from the Neo4j. There is no write operation through Application. Some ETL tool will add data to the Graph DB and i want to take the backup on completion of data load activity. IS it still unadvisable to copy over the store directory as at the time of copying there will be no write operation.